# getting results using foreach in c#

Tags: c#, foreach

```
//START OF WORKING PART//
var sizeds = 21;
var xarrayds = new int[sizeds];
var x = new double[sizeds];

for (int i = 0; i < sizeds; i++)
{
     xarrayds[i] = i;
     x[i] = xPT / 20 * xarrayds[i];
}
MessageBox.Show(x[5].ToString());
//END OF WORKING PART//

//START OF NOT WORKING PART//
double xstar;
double[] xoverhdarray = new double[] {-5, -4, -3};
foreach (double xoverhd in xoverhdarray)
{
    xstar = (xoverhd + 0.5) * 2;

    MessageBox.Show(xstar{-5}.ToString()); 
    //CAN'T FIND CORRECT SYNTAX ON THIS LINE
}
//NOT WORKING PART//
```

as you can see above, in the working part I get the result of x[5]. I want to do the same thing in second part. I couldn't find the correct syntax. I just wanna get the result of xstar variable when xoverhd is -5

How should i write that line of code? I want output to be (-5 + 0.5) * 2 = -9.

edit: I guess it's not possible to get a result outside foreach.

```
double xstar;
double[] xoverhdarray = new double[] {-5, -4, -3};
foreach (double xoverhd in xoverhdarray)
{
    xstar = (xoverhd + 0.5) * 2;
}
 MessageBox.Show(xstar{-5}.ToString());
```

guess this is invalid.

Comment: the way the indentation and variable names are structured means I can't keep up...

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: i will try to simplify my question. just a second.

Comment: What is "Hd" and where is it declared?

Comment: i cleared unnecessary variables.

Comment: What is `xstar{-5}`? The `{-5}` part shouldn't be there for sure.

Comment: Did you want this? _string message = $"({xoverhdarray[xoverhd ]} + 0.5) * 2 = {xstar} "; MessageBox.Show(message);_

Comment: that is the line i'm trying to figure out. I can't find the correct syntax.. it was x[5] in first part. but it doesn't work on second part. I don't know how to write it.

Comment: `if(xstar<=-5) {MessageBox.Show(xstar.ToString());}`?

Comment: if statements don't help me. If you look at the working part, I get the result of a selected variable. I need to do exact same thing

Comment: I hope you're also aware that the two loops do different things - the first one fills two arrays with values and after the loop is finished you grab the sixth value from one of the arrays for a message box. The second one iterates over an array and calculates a value that is stored in `xstar` (which gets overwritten on every iteration) - which is why nobody knows what you are really trying to do

Comment: Are you actually aware **why** and **how** `x[5]` in your working part is giving you the correct result? I get the feeling that your working part is just somehow working but you don't actually understand the reason. Sorry if I'm wrong on this part. Understanding your working code can help you writing more working code.

Comment: even "trying your suggestions" takes a lot of time. for a beginner, these are really difficult. I'll reply when I'm done trying. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put it in If statement, and you will get your result.

```
 if(xoverhd == -5)
      MessageBox.Show(xstar.ToString());
```

Comment: if statements won't work for me because i'll get the result for each value in array.

Comment: I tought that you want to check each value, but to write out just one, where xoverhd==-5. This way you only write out value in messageBox where xoverhd==-5.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    double xstar;
    double[] xoverhdarray = new double[] { -5, -4, -3 };
    double userChoice = -5;

    foreach (double xoverhd in xoverhdarray)
    {
        xstar = (xoverhd + 0.5) * 2;

        if (xoverhd == userChoice)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xstar.ToString()); //Outputs result of calculation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I start the program, It shows 3 different output in order. (because I have 3 variable in array) I don't need to see all of them. I need to see one of them. xoverhd= -4 for example.

Comment: So you only want to output ONE variable from the array? How do you choose which one you want? If you want to retrieve the output of -4 do you want to select it using `xstar[-4].ToString()` ?

Comment: I edited my answer to match what I think you want. You would have to get the user's choice and store it (in a variable such as `userChoice`) then compare the values inside the array to the user's choice. If they match, then output that specific result.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But when I write it like that, i get the error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'double' "

Comment: If you're trying to find a specific value in the array then use the way I did it in my edited answer above. If you try to do `xstar[-5]` it's looking for the INDEX `-5` which won't exist, seeing as your array goes from 0-2 (three elements). You need to compare the value inside against user input to find what you want.

Comment: I understand now. I guess foreach is not a great way to do what i want.

Comment: Well if you use the code in my answer it will work. If you want to write it like `MessageBox.Show(MyChoice(-5));` then create a method `public string MyChoice(double userChoice)` and place all the code from main inside there. Then you can pass through any double value that you know is inside the array to the `MyChoice()` method and inside it use the `userChoice` variable as I did. At the end of the method just `return xstar.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
//START OF NOT WORKING PART//
double xstar;
double[] xoverhdarray = new double[] { -5, -4, -3 };
foreach (double xoverhd in xoverhdarray)
{
    if (xoverhd == -5)
    {
        xstar = (xoverhd + 0.5) * 2;
        MessageBox.Show(xstar.ToString());
    }
}
//NOT WORKING PART//
```